# 3's a crowd. Particle me but may i have this dance?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, vacuum, particle-accelerators

In a particle accelerator (built for 3 particles), could we smash them into a vacuum with only enough space for 2 particles?(electrons, protons, neutrons) what would be the result?

Answer (score 1):

The way this is normally done, the particles to be smashed are whipped up to high speed in opposite directions and then collided into each other head-on. This means each individual collision involves two particles at a time, rather than three.

The idea of forcing three particles to occupy the space normally filled by two doesn't have much meaning in this context, given the fact that the particles involved (electrons and quarks) are essentially point-like, with zero size.